# Why does calling asyncio.sleep causes websocket connection to close?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I am trying to build a websockets server where the client connects and sends a request of some kind, and then the server adds that request to a queue and returns something back when finished.

to simulate the process of queueing and waiting for tasks to finish, I called asyncio.sleep whenever the process is supposed to be called.

however, whenever I do that I get the following error from the client-side:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/server/client1.py", line 10, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(message())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\server\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:/Python/server/client1.py", line 8, in message
    print(await socket.recv())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\server\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 509, in recv
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\server\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 812, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: code = 1000 (OK), no reason
```

and this error from the server-side:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<queue_dispatcher() done, defined at D:/RamNew2020/Python/server/asyncserver.py:39> exception=ConnectionClosedOK('code = 1000 (OK), no reason')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/server/asyncserver.py", line 45, in queue_dispatcher
    await data_from_q.sendto_websocket("yay")
  File "D:/Python/server/asyncserver.py", line 20, in sendto_websocket
    await self.mywebsocket.send(message)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\server\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 555, in send
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\server\lib\site-packages\websockets\protocol.py", line 803, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: code = 1000 (OK), no reason
```

My scripts:

server.py:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import datetime
import random

queue = asyncio.Queue()

async def rnd_sleep(t):
    # sleep for T seconds on average
    await asyncio.sleep(t * random.random() * 2)

#When a client sends a message the information is saved in a Request object,
#including the socket connection
class Request:
    def __init__(self, mywebsocket, mydat):
        self.mywebsocket = mywebsocket
        self.mydat = mydat
        self.start_time_of_request = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.id = random.randint(0, 128)

    async def sendto_websocket(self, message):
        await self.mywebsocket.send(message)

    def get_dat(self):
        return self.mydat

    def get_start_time(self):
        return self.start_time_of_request


async def add_to_queue(websocket, path):
    global queue
    dat = await websocket.recv()
    base64dat = Request(websocket, dat)
    await queue.put(base64dat)


#problem in queue_dispatcher


async def queue_dispatcher(q):
    while True:
        data_from_q = await q.get()
        print(data_from_q.id)

        await asyncio.sleep(1) #The problem is here, whenever I remove it, it works
        await data_from_q.sendto_websocket("yay")
        q.task_done()


async def main():
    global queue
    asyncio.create_task(queue_dispatcher(queue))
    pass

start_server = websockets.serve(add_to_queue, 'localhost', 5000)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

client.py:

```
import asyncio

async def message():
    async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:5000")as socket:
        msg = input("What do you want to send: ")
        await socket.send(msg)
        print(await socket.recv())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(message())
```

In addition, whenever I try to await any other async function, it works fine no matter how long.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that when you call `websockets.serve(add_to_queue, ...)`, `add_to_queue` is treated as a coroutine that serves the particular client. When the coroutine returns, the connection to the client is severed. So you shouldn't return from `add_to_queue` until you are done with that client. (And don't worry about serving other clients, asyncio can execute multiple independent `add_to_queue` coroutins concurrently.) I'm not sure what is the purpose of your queue architecture, but you should try communicating with the client from inside `add_to_queue`.

Comment: Things work when you remove the `sleep` likely because then websockets simply don't get the chance to close the connection yet. If you insist on keeping the queue-based design, you can add `self.done = asyncio.Event()` to `Request.__init__` and put `await base64dat.done.wait()` at the end of `add_to_queue`. When you no longer need the websocket, just call `self.done.set()` in the `Request`, and `add_to_queue` will finish and disconnect the websocket.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you for your answers! I insist on using a queue-based design since the actual process I'm going to run is very memory intensive and it crashed my computer when I tried sending 3 different requests at once on a flask server. the thing is it's only asyncio.sleep() that causes problem. when I await any other coroutine (even minutes long) it doesn't close the connection.

Comment: Queue-based design won't change anything in regards to memory usage. As for the other coroutines, I guess it depends on what they do. But if my comments in fact don't fix your problem, I will delete them, as they are just a guess...